Number Theory Find the condition when the implication $a^2+b^2=0\mod p \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=0\mod p^2$ is true
So I had to find the condition (for $a$, $b$, $p$; $p$ is prime) when $$ (condition) \iff (a^2+b^2 \equiv 0\mod p \Rightarrow a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \mod p^2)$$ is true.
When $a \equiv 0\pmod p$ and $b \equiv 0\pmod p$ it is always true, but there are non-trivial cases when $a \neq 0\pmod p$ and $b \neq 0\pmod p$ and the implication is correct (ex. $a = 3, b = 4, p = 5$)
I tried to express $a^2+b^2 \equiv 0\pmod p$ as:
$$(q_1*p + r_1)^2 + (q_2*p + r_2)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ in $[-\frac{p-1}{2}; \frac{p-1}{2}]$ to get:
$$p^2(q_1^2+q_2^2) + 2p(q_1*r_1 + q_2*r_2) + (r_1^2+r_2^2) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
The only thing I realised is that $r_1^2 \equiv -r_2^2 \pmod p$ and I don't know what to do next.
Also, it may be useful: for every $p=
4k+3$ this implication works because for these primes a and b can only be congurent to $0$ mod $p$ and every $p=4k+1$ it is true that: $a^2+b^2 = p$ has a unique soultion with $a\le b$ but I have not managed to do sth with it yet(

Not following.  $3^2+4^2=25$, for example, so there are non-trivial solutions $\pmod {p^2}$ for some $p$.

Hensel's lemma lets you take a solution mod $p$ and lift to mod $p^2$ to satisfy it, but it won't always be the case. In particular, suppose $a^2+b^2=0\mod p$ then you can look at $(a+cp)^2+(b+dp)^2=0 \mod p^2$ and you end up with $\frac{a^2+b^2}{p}+2ac+2bd=0 \mod p$ which lets you solve for $c$ in terms of $d$ which has $p$ choices. So "on average" this is only true $\frac{1}{p}$ of the time.

@lulu that's the thing, there are non-trivial solutions and I don't know whether it is possible to set some common condition for all non-trivial cases.
All I know is that non-trivial solutions appear only for p=4k+1

Oh sorry, I made a mistake when I posted, yeah, there are non-trivial cases, ty!

What do you mean by the condition? You could just put the same statement on both sides of the equivalence and be done. But surely that's not what you're after...?

@Servaes The condition should be some convenient criteria for a,b and p that it could be possible to quickly determine whether the implication is correct. E.x. if $p=4k+3$ or $p=4k+1$ and $a^2≡−1 \mod p$ ⟺ $a^2+b^2$ ≡ $0 \mod p$ ⇒ $a^2+b^2$ ≡ $0\mod p^2$
(this is just illustration)
